# (Re-)enable IntelliJ IDEA's notification to run npm install after clicking "do not show again"

Tags: javascript, npm, intellij-idea, npm-install

Intellij IDEA has this very nice feature to show a notification when the `package.json` has changed to ask if it should run `npm install` (or whatever package manager you are using).

I used this happily for many years. But some weeks ago I accidentally clicked on the "do not show again" button in the notification. And since then I try to re-enable this feature again...

In the settings there is "Appearance & Behavior > Notifications > Don't ask again notifications" - but this list is empty. And I also checked the list of system notifications and didn't find one that sounds like it. I also searched "Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript" without finding anything.

Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Hit Shift-Shift to invoke Search everywhere, then locate and use "Enable Notifications about Installing Dependencies from package.json" option.